# Nokogiri: Target the sibling of a table with an image

Tags: html, ruby, parsing, nokogiri

I'm trying to target a table in the `tr` of an outer table. The first `tr` of the outer table contains a `table` with an image which identifies the table's data. There are several outer tables with different images, one for each of the data types. I can target the image in Nokogiri using

```
page.css('table tr table tr img[@src="images/bicycyles.gif"]')
```

I want to get at the data, which is in a table in the third `tr` of the outer table. I can target all the data on the page with

```
page.css('table[bgcolor="#FFFFFF"] tr[valign="top"]')
```

but that also pulls in data from other data types (e.g. under "cars.gif").

How can I combine these searches to only find the bicycle data? I basically want to say "extract the text from the `tr` with `valign=top` in a `table` with `bgcolor=#ffffff`, which is a sibling of the `tr` containing an `img src=bicycles.gif`

Here's an example of the HTML:

```
<!-- Outer Table -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="10" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table> 
                <tr>
                    <!-- Info must have this particular image preceding it -->
                    <td><img src="images/bicycle.gif" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="100" height="10" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="532"> 
                <tr>
                    <td>Info</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <tr valign="top">
                    <!-- The info I want to extract -->
                    <td>Bicycle Name</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- More trs with different data types --> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "extract the text from the `tr` with `valign=top` in a `table` with
>   `bgcolor=#ffffff`, which is a sibling of the `tr` containing an `img
>   src=bicycles.gif`"

Slight correction based on the example HTML:

> "extract the text from the `tr` with `valign=top` in a `table` with
>   `bgcolor=#ffffff`, which is contained within a `tr` having a preceding `tr` sibling which itself contains an `img src=bicycles.gif`"

Converted into XPath:

```
page.xpath('//tr[preceding-sibling::tr//img/@src = "images/bicycle.gif"]//table[@bgcolor="#FFFFFF"]//tr[@valign="top"]').text.strip

#=> "Bicycle Name"
```

Note that in the example you gave, you either need `[bgcolor="#FFFFFF"]` or `[valign="top"]` but not both. Since relying on hardcoded styles is not ideal, the less you need to specify the better.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry, the HTML above is a simplification, the actual one has other tables with `#ffffff` and no `valign`, that's why I'm using both. Is there a way to limit the `preceding-sibling` to either exactly 2 back, or from 1-3 back? When I try this xpath selector, it keeps seeing the `tr` with an `img` as a sibling, even though it's further and further back. Thanks.

Comment: Found the preceding-sibling thing by myself: `preceding-sibling::tr[2]`. Thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

It's still messy but more readable I think with css:

```
page.at('img[src="images/bicycle.gif"]').ancestors('tr')[1].at('~ tr tr[valign=top] td').text
#=> "Bicycle Name"
```